# In which .php file does wordpress print out the blog titles, dates, authors on index.php (main blog listing)

Tags: php, wordpress

I was curious because I needed to make some modifications to the code markup of each of my displayed blog posts in the index.php listing.

I don't mean something like the_post(), I want to see the lowest level function where the raw html is being inputted. There is one line of html I need to append to all of my blogs so that the google authorship works.

I'm getting Warning: Missing required field "updated". in the rich snippet tool. No plugins serve this unfortunately.

This is what my theme's index.php looks like as of now:

```
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

               <?php get_template_part( 'content', ( post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'post-formats' ) ? get_post_format() : get_post_type() ) ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

               <?php get_template_part( 'loop-error' ); // Loads the loop-error.php template. ?>

        ?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the relevant part of content.php

```
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="<?php hybrid_entry_class(); ?>">

                    <div class="post-content">

                            <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'entry_title', '[entry-title permalink="0"]' ); ?>

                            <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'byline', '<div class="byline">' . __( '[entry-published] &middot; by [entry-author] &middot; in [entry-terms taxonomy="category" before=""] [entry-edit-link before=" &middot; "]', 'ascetica' ) . '</div>' ); ?>

                            <div class="entry-content">

                                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<p class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'ascetica' ), 'after' => '</p>' ) ); ?>

                            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                            <?php echo apply_atomic_shortcode( 'entry_meta', '<div class="entry-meta">' . __( '[entry-terms taxonomy="post_tag" before="Tags: "]', 'ascetica' ) . '</div>' ); ?>

                            <?php do_atomic( 'close_entry' ); // ascetica_close_entry ?>

                    </div><!-- .post-content -->

            </div><!-- .hentry -->
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default themes index.php file directly handle those from inside the loop. Your theme may have some difference.
Here is a visual of WordPress template files hierarchy http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Comment: I believe my theme may have a difference. This is the theme i'm using http://themehybrid.com/themes/ascetica, in the index.php page all I can see is the_post() calls under a while ( has_nextpost() )

Comment: This theme has a home.php file which is handling the home page.
Check that and also check the content.php file which is using by home.php.

Comment: I opened up the home.php and it looks identical to the index.php (which I added the code to in the comments above), thank you for responding so far.

Comment: Check content.php file which is using by home.php

Comment: It appears that you have found the file! Thanks a lot, now if you don't mind me asking... how do I go about adding this one line of html. I notice that there are a lot of methods on this form "apply_atomic_shortcode". Must I use this to add my line of code? The Line i'd like to add is <span class="updated">112</span> as a "date" prefixing my articles, thanks. Ill edit my content.php in the main post

Comment: That's not a must. You can just write plain HTML inside the loop.
But be sure to backup before editing any code.